# IComparable.CompareTo - Implement asynchronous compare that waits on button press

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, sorting, asynchronous

I'm writing a small app that helps me sort pictures in order of their subjective quality. I'm not interested in implementing a machine learning solution, so I decided to go with a user-directed sort in which the user is presented with pairs of pictures and is required to select which of the pair is the better picture (or if they're both at the same quality).

Instead of trying to split something like quicksort or insertion sort in half, I decided to go with the existing `OrderBy` LINQ method, which works on objects implementing `IComparable<T>`. The desired code path is as follows

1. `OrderBy` calls `CompareTo` on my `UserSortable<T>`.
2. `CompareTo` calls two callbacks that sets each `PictureBox` so the user can see them.
3. `CompareTo` then waits until the user makes a selection. The `PictureBox.Click` event handler tells something like a `CancellationTokenSource` to stop waiting.
4. Which `PictureBox` was clicked is stored as a property on the form that the `UserSortable<T>` has a reference to - its value is checked and used as the result of `CompareTo`.

The problem, as of now, is in step 3. `CancellationTokenSource` does support cancellation from the form's click event, but it throws a `TaskCanceledException` as I try to actually get the result.

Additionally, because `int IComparable<T>.CompareTo(T)` is an existing interface, I cannot await call anything from it, leading me to do the hackish `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` method.

What's the best way to go about implementing this?

Code: `UserSortable<T>`

```
internal sealed class UserSortable<T> : IComparable<UserSortable<T>>
    {
        private UserDirectedSortForm form;
        private Action<T> setFirstItem;
        private Action<T> setSecondItem;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;
        internal T Item { get; private set; }

        public UserSortable(UserDirectedSortForm form, T item, Action<T> setFirstItem, Action<T> setSecondItem)
        {
            this.form = form;
            this.Item = item;
            this.setFirstItem = setFirstItem;
            this.setSecondItem = setSecondItem;
        }

        public async Task CompareTo(UserSortable<T> other)
        {
            setFirstItem(Item);
            setSecondItem(other.Item);

            form.CancellationToken = cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await WaitForUserSelection();
        }

        private async Task<int> AssignResult(UserSortable<T> other)
        {
            await CompareTo(other);
            int result = 0;

            if (form.Selected == 'A') { result = -1; }
            else if (form.Selected == 'B') { result = 1; }
            else if (form.Selected == '=') { result = +1; }
            else { result = int.MaxValue; }

            return result;
        }

        private Task WaitForUserSelection()
        {
            return Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken.Token);
        }

        int IComparable<UserSortable<T>>.CompareTo(UserSortable<T> other)
        {
            return AssignResult(other).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
```

`UserDirectedSortForm`

```
public partial class UserDirectedSortForm : Form
    {
        internal CancellationTokenSource CancellationToken { get; set; }
        private List<UserSortable<int>> items;
        internal char Selected { get; set; }

        public UserDirectedSortForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int first = 0;
            int second = 0;

            Action<int> setFirst = i => first = i;
            Action<int> setSecond = i =>
            {
                second = i;
                string newText = $"Which is larger? {first} or {second}?";
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label1.Text = newText; });
            };

            items = new List<UserSortable<int>>();
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 0, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 4, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 12, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 3, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 13, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 4, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 26, setFirst, setSecond));
            items.Add(new UserSortable<int>(this, 543221, setFirst, setSecond));
        }

        private void AssignResult(char result)
        {
            Selected = result;

            try
            {
                using (CancellationToken)
                {
                    CancellationToken.Cancel();
                }

                CancellationToken = null;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                ;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignResult('A');
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignResult('B');
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignResult('=');
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(i => i))
                {
                    builder.Append(item.Item);
                    builder.Append(", ");
                }
                MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your form is created on the original thread, but then used in a background thread in `AssignResult()`. I'm not sure off hand what I'd do to fix that, but I do know that WinForms controls can/should only be used on the same thread where they were created.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do a waiting-for-button comparison on the UI thread without blocking it, though.

Comment: I don't think using `OrderBy` is a particularly good idea here. Humans are humans and it can realistically happen that `I(mage)1` will be "better" than `I2`, `I3` can be "better" than `I2`, yet `I1` might end up "better" than 'I3`, thus breaking the comparison logic

Comment: Ah, right... didn't think of that. Without transitivity between members, no total order can be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention by Anton Gogolev in the comments, user-directed sorts cannot work because transitivity (A>B, B>C, therefore A>C) cannot be guaranteed, and thus no user-sorted collections can have a total order or even assigned numeric qualities based on their quality relative to other items.

I can force transitivity by doing something like binary insertion sort, but that might still be wrong (forcing transitivity where there is none also makes the order wrong). I'll probably just end up doing a star rating system.